# como redireccionar mi dominio a mi sitio web en nodejs en mi servidor vps (hostinger)

Tags: html, nodejs, hosting, dominio, vps

tengo una web en node subida a hostinger, a un vps, y en la publc_html si pongo un index.html al entrar a mi_dominio.es me lo renderiza, pero si lo quito no, pero puedo entrar por mi_dominio.es:3080 que es el puerto de mi web, alguien sabe como hacer que al poner directamente mi_dominio.es me saque esa web, ahora mismo me salta un 404 propio de hostinger, ya que no encuentra ningún index.html ni nada, pero no se como redireccionar al puerto en el que está la aplicación, el código de mi server.js es este, en local me funciona todo perfectamente y si accedo a la web por la ip y el puerto o el dominio y el puerto también me funciona todo perfectamente, estoy usando un SO Centos y mi servidor es Apache

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3080;
const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require("path");

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))

 
//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

//HBS
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');




//rutas
app.use(require('./routes/index')); 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Corriendo en el puerto ${port}`));
```

alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto y que me saque mi web en nodejs? muchas gracias

Comment: Primero, ¿Que en que distro **linux** esta montado el **VPS**?, segundo usas ¿ **Apache** o **Nginx** ?

Comment: no lo se, solamente se que tengo un centos con un cyberpanel, como puedo saber eso otro?

Comment: Bien ya sabemos que la distro es **Centos**, puedes ver su versión en el panel de administración de **hostinger**, desconozco que es **cyberpanel**, pero para que tu dominio atienda ese puerto se requiere configurar un server como **Apache** por ejemplo, puedes claro, instalarlo o verificar si ya esta instalado a través de **SSH**

Comment: Ejecutando el comando `httpd -v` a través de **SSH** puedes ver si ya esta instalado, aunque no creo que lo este

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 16 2020 16:18:20
 es un apache

Comment: Perfecto, como te decía no se lo que es **cyberpanel** pero supongo que solo es un *panel de gestión* como **Webmin** así que te daré una respuesta para que puedas configurar esto. Mientras tanto, edita tu pregunta y añade que estas usando tanto, **Centos** como **Apache**

Comment: gracias, si efectivamente cyberpanel es un panel de gestión, ya he puesto que estoy usando centos y apache, muchas gracias, pero como puedo hacer para redireccionar a mi web?

Comment: No te preocupes ya te redacto la respuesta

Comment: perfectoo muchas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127835/discussion-between-josbert-and-hector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, como te decía en los comentarios, para que tu **dominio** pueda atender el puerto sobre el que esta corriendo tu aplicación **node.js** es necesario configurar un **proxy** inverso a ese puerto, en la mayoría de la de las distribuciones **linux** es casi igual, ya que solo necesitamos:

1. Instalar un administrador de procesos como [**pm2**](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)
2. Configurar el **proxy inverso** en un servidor (en este caso **Apache2**)

Ya que tu servidor **Apache** esta instalado y corriendo, vamos a instalar **pm2**

**¿Que hace pm2?**

Sencillo, **pm2** es un *administrador de procesos*, que de manera sencilla, lo que hará es hacer que tu aplicación siga corriendo después de cerrar la conexión **ssh** y también reiniciara el proceso en caso de haya algún problema:

```sh
# instalamos pm2 con npm de manera global

$ sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
```

Inicias el servidor **node.js** con **pm2**, supongamos que tu proyecto esta en un directorio como `/var/www/html/myapp`

```sh
# inicias tu serve.js con pm2

$ pm2 start /var/www/html/myapp/server.js
```

Esto iniciara tu servidor, arrancando un proceso de **pm2** con el nombre de tu `server.js` sin la extensión de dicho archivo, ejemplo:

```sh
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ server   │ 0  │ fork │ 30099 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 9.999 MB    │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Hacemos que este proceso se inicie automáticamente en caso de que tu servidor se reinicie

```sh
$ sudo pm2 startup systemd

# Guardamos la lista de procesos actual
$ pm2 save
```

Con esto debería bastar, tu aplicación estará corriendo en el puerto que usas, de manera segura gracias a **pm2**

**Ahora configuraremos el proxy inverso**

Supongo que **Apache** ya tendrá una configuración para tu dominio, en la ruta que esta tu proyecto, entonces configuraremos el **proxy inverso**. Para ello debes abrir en tu consola el archivo de configuración de tus **virtual host** de apache

Este archivo debería estar en en el directorio `/etc/httpd/sites-available`, con un nombre como `000-default.conf`

```sh
# Abrimos el archivo
$ sudo vi /etc/httpd/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Veras en unas lineas, algo como `<VirtualHost *:80> ...` y tal vez mas abajo el nombre de tu dominio, entonces allí agregas la configuración:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tudominio.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    
    # Tal vez veas algo mas por acá
    # pero lo que necesitas son las siguientes lineas

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego de agregar y eso y guardar los cambios del archivo, reiniciamos **Apache**

```sh
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Con esto debería bastar, tu nombre de dominio quedaría atendiendo a tu aplicación **node.js**, espero te sirva

**Nota:**

> No se que tantos conocimientos tengas de **linux** pero te doy un
> pequeño dato: si ves un sigo de `#` en cambio del `$`, al inicio de la linea en tu consola al
> conectar por **ssh**, significa que ya tienes permisos **root**, así
> que ahorrate anteponer el `sudo` que yo puse en los comandos

Saludos :)

Comment: muchas gracias, pero no tengo sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: tengo un httpd.conf dentro de etc/httpd/conf

Comment: pero no tiene lo de virtualHost

Comment: @Héctor en ese archivo debes tener una linea como esta `IncludeOptional sites-available/*.conf` si no esta o esta comentada con un `#`, entonces agrega lo que te puse a ese archivo `httpd.conf`

Comment: Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: al hacer el systemctl status httpd.service, me dice failed to start the apache http service, he pegado eso al principio del todo

Comment: Significa que ya esta corriendo un **host** en el puerto `80`, es porque tiene que estar el archivo `000-default.conf` en algún lado o tiene otro nombre, elimina el **host** que acabas de agregar a `httpd.conf` y has un `ls -a` dentro de `/etc/httpd/sites-available`

Comment: no tengo la carpeta sites-available

Comment: tengo conf conf.d conf.modules.d logs modules run

Comment: en conf.modules.d tengo 00-base.conf  00-lua.conf  00-proxy.conf    01-cgi.conf
00-dav.conf   00-mpm.conf  00-systemd.conf

Comment: moveré esto al chat, un momento

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127836/discussion-between-hector-and-josbert).

Comment: creo que se cerró el chat, ahora el dominio no carga nada ni la ip sola

Comment: he reiniciado el servidor apache y ahora el dominio me saca lo de testing de apache

Comment: he puesto el archivo 000-default.conf en sites-available y en sites-enabled y ahora me carga la web pero sin los css ni nada

Comment: lo he conseguidoo!! muchas gracias, en el archivo del VirtualHost he puesto :puerto/ con la / al final me funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto..!! amigo